# Count how many times a user logs with Node/Express/Passport

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

We are running a Node/Express app that uses passport to authenticate and we want to record when a user logs in.  Is that something we can put in the `Strategy` ? does it have to go into our callback? Is there a way to get it from `passport.authenticate` ?

Comment: In passport.authenticate you are probably querying db to check user's name and password so if the query returns a user you can update that user immediately. Add something like numberOfLogins to your user schema and keep updating it with every login

Comment: @Molda thanks, I looked at the passport.authenticate() and learned a lot about how it works (as it was provided as an IBM npm module.) What I ended up doing is in the definition of the Strategy we provide a validate callback function to be run after successful login, currently it just puts the accessToken and refreshToken into the profile, so I added a call out to a function that puts a new record into our JSON doc store Cloudant. Works like a charm, thanks for the help!!